# How can i fill a char array with some string , en int

Tags: c++, mbed

I have a question about a char array:
I have a form '"1"+lapcounter+":"+seconds' that must come in a char array.
How can i fill this array in this form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have some numeric variables which you want to format into a string, use a string-stream for that:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "1" << lapcounter << ":" << seconds";
```

Now you can extract a string from that:

```
std::string s = ss.str();
```

and if you really want a character array for some reason (which I'm sure you don't)

```
char const * cs = s.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf`, or `snprintf`. This function works similar to `printf` but instead of standard output, the output will go to char array you specified. For example:

```
char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "1%d:%d", lapcounter, seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_string` is used like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    int lapcounter = 23;
    std::string str("1");
    str.append(std::to_string(lapcounter ));
    str.append(":seconds");
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```
123:seconds
```

if you really need a char array you get that from `ss.c_str()`